# Getting an absolute positioned div under another div

Tags: css, css-position

Absolute div keeps showing up above the other divs, while is should appear underneath;
here is a quick demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/hvP8c/2/

```
<div id="logo">
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="line"></div>
</div>
#logo {
    position: relative;
}
h1 {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#eee;
    z-index:100;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#line {
    border-bottom:1px solid #033e5e;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:30px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

In this demo, the line should go below the circle. I tried to play with z-index but it didn't have any effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` only applies to positioned elements. Since the `h1` (which appears to be the "other div" you are talking about) is `position: static` it won't apply there.

Set `position: relative` on the `h1`

Comment: Thank you! That was the most detailed answer for me to understand my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `position: relative` or `position: absolute` to h1

Answer (score 0):

Change `z-index` for `#line` from 1 to -1:

```
#line {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hvP8c/4/

Beware that it may not work on IE6/7. OK in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

just do => z-index:-1; of the id '#line'